# Как установить .exe файл в веб сайт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, exe

Есть такая игра под названием Typing Test, вопрос, как можно установить .exe файл в веб сайт? или есть другие способы установить такое приложение на веб сайт?

Comment: В смысле для скачивания? Или для чего? Какая полная задача?

Comment: нет, чтобы смогли играть люди

Comment: никак (10 символов)

Comment: Не понял, вы хотите, чтобы при заходе на сайт на компьютере пользователя начинал выполняться произвольный exe-файл?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Или как то скачать приложение из этого сайта к себе на сайт  https://www.typingtest.com/